# Two definitions for "Run as administrator"?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, shortcuts, administrator, runas

In my Total Commander icon properties, I see `Run as administrator` in two places: the Compatibility tab settings, and the Shortcut tab (Advanced button).

[image]

[image]

**Question**

Are they both the same?  If not, what's the difference?

Comment: This dupe Q&A are much better quality than the original from 2009. IMHO this question should be closed and the authors should migrate their content over to the original.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**The Compatibility tab settings are linked to the executable.**  They will take effect when opening any shortcut to the executable or the executable itself.  The Compatibility settings also apply for all users if you select those options.

**The Shortcut settings apply to that specific shortcut.**  You could create two shortcuts: one as administrator, one not as.

Note: The properties dialog for an executable does not have a shortcut tab.

Comment: Also note that the Compatibility tab is disabled for some executeables, mainly those of Windows itself.

Comment: @Sebazzz This is probably related to those compatibility GUIDs in the manifest: If an executable explicitly says it's compatible with the current Windows version, don't emulate an earlier one.